# Can't deserialize data from Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

In my Spring Boot applications I used *Kafka* and *Spark*, where Spark read a stream from Kafka, transform data and finally send the result to Kafka:

```
StreamingQuery kafka = scoring
                .writeStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .outputMode(OutputMode.Complete())
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
                .option("topic", outputTopic)
                .option("checkpointLocation", "~/Desktop/checkpoint")
                .queryName("urlCounterKafkaStream")
                .start();
```

The data which sends by Spark has 2 fields (name, count).

On kafka listener application I implemented simple deserializer as below:

```
public class RSSItemDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<RSSItemDTO> {
    public RSSItemDeserializer() {
        super(RSSItemDTO.class);
    }
}
```

And set that on application.properties

```
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=com.noname.deserializer.RSSItemDeserializer
```

But have serialization exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition urlCounterStream-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 119, 119, 119, 46, 48, 53, 53, 50, 46, 117, 97]] from topic [urlCounterStream]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'https': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: (byte[])"https://www.0552.ua"; line: 1, column: 7]
```

Am I missed something? How to solve that and deserialize data?

Thanks!

Comment: `https` is invalid, `true, false or null` was expected. Probable in `byte[])"https://www.0552.ua"`. Are you sure the record and the data have the same structure?

Comment: `"https://www.0552.ua"` is a String, not JSON or an `RSSItemDTO`. Plus there is only one field, not two

Comment: You are right. The problem was in different types, but spark provide method `toJSON()` which solved this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I supposed that spark by default sents data as json. Solution for this case is to use `toJSON()` method on our result and after that send it to kafka as

```
StreamingQuery kafka = scoring.toJSON()
                .writeStream()
                ...
```

Maybe for someone it will be helpful.